# Highlighting text in OneNote on an iPad with Apple Pencil

Tags: ipad, onenote, stylus

I’m trying to highlight typed text on my iPad in OneNote with an Apple Pencil. I am able to do this with the highlighter option on the Draw tab, but the highlights are ink. If I insert a line of text above my highlights, the text shifts but the ink highlights don’t.

Is there a way to use the text highlighting on the Home tab with the Apple Pencil? When I try, I can select the text highlight tool with the Apple Pencil, but when I try to use it, it draws ink when I try to highlight text.

Or is there a way to get the ink to shift with text if I insert lines without having to jump through hoops?

Comment: Which app are you using? If you use the Pencil in Notes and double tap on a word it'll be highlighted. You can then further highlight more text by moving the left and right handles.

Comment: Sorry, it was tagged as OneNote before the question was migrated here. Updated above.

Comment: Have you tried unchecking the option "Apple Pencil Always Draws Ink" in the settings under "Apple Pencil"?